# Map Marker refresh/Update without refreshing whole map

Tags: javascript, php

I cannot figure out how to edit this to make it so the map does not refresh but it continues to refresh the marker to get the updated positions.

the positions are coming from
 this line

```
<?php

$json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json");
     ?>
```

right there

```
<?php

$json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json");
     ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
    <title>SA:MP live map</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map-canvas { display: inline-block; height: 800px; width: 800px; }
        #map-legend { padding: 10px; background-color: rgba(141, 142, 127, 0.46);}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script src="js/SanMap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p_pos = <?php echo (empty($json_pos)) ? "" : $json_pos ?>;

        var mapType = new SanMapType(0, 1, function (zoom, x, y) {
            return x == -1 && y == -1 
            ? "images/tiles/map.outer.png" 
            : "images/tiles/map." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
        });

        var satType = new SanMapType(0, 3, function (zoom, x, y) {
            return x == -1 && y == -1 
            ? null 
            : "images/tiles/sat." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
        });

        var map = SanMap.createMap(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
            {'Map': mapType, 'Satellite': satType}, 2, SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(0,0), false, 'Satellite');

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(document.getElementById('map-legend'));

        if(p_pos !== "")
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(p_pos).length; i++) 
            {
                if(p_pos[i].online == 1) createMarker(i); 
            }
        }   

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            var pos = SanMap.getPosFromLatLng(event.latLng);
            console.log(pos.x + "," + pos.y);
        }); 

        function createMarker(id)
        {
            var p_windows = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<p>"+p_pos[id].name+" <b>(ID: "+id+")</b><br>Ping: "+p_pos[id].ping+"</p>"
            });

            var p_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y),
                map: map,
                icon: "images/marker.png"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(p_marker, 'click', function() {
                p_windows.open(map,p_marker);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: There are only two events in the script listed -- both `Click`, one on `map`, and one on `marker`. If you don't do anything, it should not have anything triggered.

Comment: I dont get what your saying.. I just want the marker positions to constantly update...

Comment: What would I add to create another function make the markers keep updating without the map refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top header line: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />` to disable refresh the page. And then add a `setInterval` function to get the new data from your php service, in the call back --

1. first use marker.setMap(null) to clear the previous marker and then call your CreateMarker(id).

Or

2. you can write an updateMarker(id) function, and use `marker.setPosition()` to update the location.

These are generally idea for you to implement your own code.

Comment: the positions are coming from $json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json"); and I get I need to remove the refresh at the top. I dont understand where I would even put the other 2 parts you mentioned in the code

Comment: Ok So I need to first do SetMap(null) where does that go though? Then right after that I am calling to the already created function of CreatMarker? Finally I need to make a whole new funtion for UpdateMarker(id) using marker.setPostion(<?php $json_pos ?>) but where and how do I call that new function?

Comment: Is this on the right track? function ChangePos(id) 
   {
       var latlng = <?php echo $json_pos ?>;
       marker.setPosition(latlng);
   }    Still not doing anything though

Comment: Make sure you have set an Interval function to periodically retrieve data from your service; make sure you have a global marker variable to save the previous marker which you refer to setPosition, make sure your latlng is a valid google.map.LatLng object or latlng literal.

Comment: Im so lost uhhg This is what I have now function updateMarker(id) 
   {
       var latlng = <?php echo $json_pos ?>;
       marker.setPosition(latlng);

   }
   var refreshMap = setInterval(updateMarker, 1000);

Comment: Can you please just use the code I provided and give me a strong example to go on.

Comment: I can do that only if you can setup an executable snippet through here or jsfiddle. I don;t have php for test.

Comment: Just write it and I will test on my localhost so the PHP works, then I will relay what happened to you.

Comment: hello, Are you still gonna help me?